# 504 Getaway time out 50 sec in EC2 error

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an application hosted on amzon EC2. we I do a AJAX request it will time out after 50 second. 
any one know how to increase this time out?

Comment: What web server are you using?   If it's Apache you can easily adjust the TimeOut directive (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#timeout)

Comment: No it is a nodejs server

Comment: I don't think EC2 has any role to play in here. The first G! search for timeout + Node.js was [this](http://contourline.wordpress.com/2011/03/30/preventing-server-timeout-in-node-js/) but there should be more resources.

Answer (score 0):

It can be increases through the AWS Console at Load Balance section